# Why are API requests being made to the wrong URL (Vue.js 2)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm fooling around trying to learn stuff (Vue.js 2 with routing) and I was wondering why whenever I was on any other routes other than the home ('/') route, said localhost url gets prepended to the appropriate url when making API calls. An example would be the following:

```
const url = `'https://www.reddit.com/r/'${ this.sub }/.json?limit=10'`; // this.sub being the corresponding subreddit string
```

which results in something like this:

'http://localhost:5000/subreddits/politics/https://www.reddit.com/r/politics/.json?limit=10'

Below is the relevant code:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                sub: this.$route.params.sub,
                posts: [],
            }
        },
        watch: {
            '$route'(to, from) {
                this.sub = to.params.sub;
            }
        },
        methods: {
          fetchPosts: async function () {
            const url = `'https://www.reddit.com/r/'${ this.sub }/.json?limit=10'`;
            try {
              const res = await (await fetch(url)).json();
              this.posts = await (res.data.children);
            } catch(err) {
              console.error(err);
            }
          }
        },
        mounted() {
          this.fetchPosts();
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your project.
1. The request whose host is reddit can't be send within localhost.
2. if you use back quote, single quote is redundant.

IF YOU USED VUE-CLI TO INIT THE PROJECT, to solve these problem, there are 2 step you should do.

1. in `/config/index.js` file, find `proxyTable`, and add this:

```

```
proxyTable: {
    '/reddit': {
        target: 'https://www.reddit.com/r',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/reddit': ''
        }
    }
}
```

2. in the relevant code:

```

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                sub: this.$route.params.sub,
                posts: [],
            }
        },
        watch: {
            '$route'(to, from) {
                this.sub = to.params.sub;
            }
        },
        methods: {
          fetchPosts: async function () {
            const url = `/reddit/'${ this.sub }/.json?limit=10`;
            try {
              const res = await (await fetch(url)).json();
              this.posts = await (res.data.children);
            } catch(err) {
              console.error(err);
            }
          }
        },
        mounted() {
          this.fetchPosts();
        },
    }
</script>
```

```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I had forgotten to get rid of the (single) quotes in the URL template literal, as you pointed out too. Doing so did the trick.